# Biblatex, backrefstyle doesn't work (f. and ff.)

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex (v3.13a) and I would like to use the manual documented function `backrefstyle=three+` but i do not get any results - it seems like not working and I don't know why.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, isbn=false, backrefstyle=three+]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\listfiles
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Heinrich.2013,
 author = {Heinrich, Michael},
 year = {2013},
 title = {Kritik der politischen {\"O}konomie: Eine Einf{\"u}hrung},
 address = {Stuttgart},
 edition = {11. Aufl.},
  publisher = {Schmetterling-Verl.},
 isbn = {3-89657-593-7},
 series = {Reihe Theorie.org}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

Dummy \autocite[39--41]{Heinrich.2013} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Still getting this]

Which should be `Dummy (Heinrich 2013: 39ff)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not what `backrefstyle` does. `backref` concerns references from the bibliography to the pages on which entries are cited. It has nothing to do with the formatting of `postnote`.

Comment: Indeed `backrefstyle` has nothing to do with the postnote format. There is a feature request open for this https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/217. At the moment I would recommend to either use `\psq`/`\psqq` manually or not to use "f."/"ff." at all (the full page range at least shows that *you* know exactly where to look and helps your reader in finding the right spot as well).